# Android Canvas is null

Tags: android, canvas, locking

Can these two expressions both be true at one time?
holder.getSurface().isValid() == true;
and
canvas = holder.lockCanvas()
canvas == null;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From references:

> isValid() - Does this object hold a valid surface? Returns true if it
>   holds a physical surface, so lockCanvas() will succeed.

So, if lockCanvas() succeeds it returns a non null canvas.

But you shouldn't access Surface directly (you need synchronization), in `surfaceChanged` you can just call `canvas = holder.lockCanvas()` and draw only if canvas is not null.

Comment: Is it meen that I need to implement SurfaceHolder.Callback and  check drawing possibility in surfaceCreated method?

Comment: the SurfaceHolder is initialized asynchronous so, basicaly if you want to draw on it you should have a SurfaceHolder.Callback (to know when it is ready), and the best place to do the drawings is in `surfaceChanged` (which is called after `surfaceCreated`) and where you are provided with `width`, `height` and `holder`.